# $\operatorname{det} \Phi(t)=1$ for all $t$ if and only if $ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}=0 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $n \times n$ matrix with constant entries.
Consider the homogeneous system $X^{\prime}=A X .$ Let $\Phi(t)$ be the fundamental matrix
of this system satisfying $\Phi(0)=I_{n \times n} .$ Show that $\operatorname{det} \Phi(t)=1$ for all $t$ if and only if
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}=0
$$
where $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{n}$ are all the (real) eigenvalues of $A$ (not necessarily distinct).

I want some hint to start the problem because I have no initial value I cannot manupulate $\psi$ fundamental solution in terms of $\phi$

Comment: exercise problems for upcoming exam week need some hint or answers, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Prove that for any matrix function
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\det(M(t))={\rm tr}(M(t)^{-1}M'(t))\det(M(t))
$$
and remember that the sum of the eigenvalues is the trace.